# Is it possible to pass a multidimensional array as a parameter in EXCEL VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, multidimensional-array

I have an array created in one procedure which is the final results, I want to utilise these results in a new procedure as inputs to the calculations there.  Is there a way to pass a multidimensional array as a parameter into another procedure?  How would you you put it into the call and how woudl you define the parameter in the procedure it will be used in?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Pass as you would a single dimension array by decorating the routine argument with parentheses;

```
sub a()
    dim x(1, 1) As long
    x(0, 0) = 1
    x(1, 1) = 4
    process x
end sub

sub process(arr() As long)
    Msgbox arr(0, 0)
    Msgbox arr(1, 1)
end sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this the sort of thing you are after?

```
Sub AAATest()
''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Dynamic array to hold
' the result.
''''''''''''''''''''''''
Dim ReturnArr() As Long
Dim Ndx1 As Long
Dim Ndx2 As Long
Dim NumDims As Long
''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' call the function to get
' the result array.
''''''''''''''''''''''''''
ReturnArr = ReturnMulti()
NumDims = NumberOfArrayDimensions(Arr:=ReturnArr)
Select Case NumDims
    Case 0
        '''''''''''''''''''
        ' unallocated array
        '''''''''''''''''''
    Case 1
        ''''''''''''''''''''''''''
        ' single dimensional array
        ''''''''''''''''''''''''''
        For Ndx1 = LBound(ReturnArr) To UBound(ReturnArr)
            Debug.Print ReturnArr(Ndx1)
        Next Ndx1
    Case 2
        '''''''''''''''''''''''''''
        ' two dimensional array
        '''''''''''''''''''''''''''
        For Ndx1 = LBound(ReturnArr, 1) To UBound(ReturnArr, 1)
            For Ndx2 = LBound(ReturnArr, 2) To UBound(ReturnArr, 2)
                Debug.Print ReturnArr(Ndx1, Ndx2)
            Next Ndx2
        Next Ndx1
    Case Else
        ''''''''''''''''''''''
        ' too many dimensions
        ''''''''''''''''''''''
End Select
End Sub


Function ReturnMulti() As Long()
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Returns a mutli-dimensional array.
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Dim A(1 To 2, 1 To 3) As Long
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' put in some values.
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
A(1, 1) = 100
A(1, 2) = 200
A(1, 3) = 300
A(2, 1) = 400
A(2, 2) = 500
A(2, 3) = 600
ReturnMulti = A()
End Function
```