# How to pass a 2D array to a procedure, and modify it inside the function? VBA

Tags: arrays, vba, ms-word

using VBA to create a Word Macro I have the following problem:

I am trying to populate a 2d array using a function. The problem is that when I try to pass the 2D array to the function, I get the following error:

> type mismatch array or user defined type expected

My macro:

```
Sub Tests()
'
' Tests Macro
'
Dim paragraphs(21, 1) As String
populate_paragraph (paragraphs)
End Sub
```

which call the procedure:

```
Sub populate_paragraph(replacers() As String)

ReDim replacers(21, 1) As String

replacers(0, 0) = "%HEADER%"
replacers(1, 0) = "%DESIGN_BRIEF_PARAGRAPH%"
...
replacers(21, 0) = "%DISCLAIMER_PARAGRAPH%"

replacers(0, 1) = create_header
replacers(1, 1) = create_design_brief_paragraph
...
replacers(21, 1) = create_disclaimer_paragraph

End Sub
```

If instead of passing the 2D array to a procedure, I try to initialize it with the return value of a function, I get the following error:

> Can't assign to an array

The code in this case is:

```
Sub Tests()
'
' Tests Macro
'
Dim paragraphs(21, 1) As String
paragraphs = populate_paragraph
End Sub
```

which call the function:

```
Function populate_paragraph() As String

Dim replacers(21, 1) As String

replacers(0, 0) = "%HEADER%"
replacers(1, 0) = "%DESIGN_BRIEF_PARAGRAPH%"
...
replacers(21, 0) = "%DISCLAIMER_PARAGRAPH%"

replacers(0, 1) = create_header
replacers(1, 1) = create_design_brief_paragraph
...
replacers(21, 1) = create_disclaimer_paragraph

populate_paragraph = replacers

End Function
```

Thank you for reading my question and for your help

Comment: You modified your question content - please change your title to match the new question

Comment: You can use paraarray or check duplicate question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34134936/access-vba-pass-a-multidimensional-array-in-a-function?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access VBA Pass a MultiDimensional Array in a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34134936/access-vba-pass-a-multidimensional-array-in-a-function)

Comment: @dbmitch It's not a duplicate, at least not exactly, since the Answer there is not optimal for what this OP is trying to do (pass as an array of data type String).

Comment: Note that I was working on my Answer before you edited and I didn't see that edit until after I posted.

Comment: You still pass the string array when the function declares its parameter as variant

Comment: But, @dbmitch, the original question specifies a String in both the calling as well as the called procedure. And does not call a function. Sure, it can be done differently, but if you want a specific data type...

Comment: @dbmitch I am afraid I did not see exactly that question, but did read many other similars. In any case, I don t think I would have been able to find my mistake just by reading it (at least not yesterday when I did the question) The explanations there helped me to understand better the other users answers to my question. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's tricky...

You have to pass the array `ByRef` since you're changing it in the procedure you're calling and this is not a Function so that you could pass it back. In this particular instance VBA insists on passing the value `ByRef`.

Linked with that is the fact that you put the parameter you're passing in parentheses: `(paragraphs())`. Since the parameter is being passed to a "method" and not a function you shouldn't use parentheses. If you do, you're telling VBA you want to pass the parameter `ByVal`.

The following works:

```
Sub Tests()
  Dim paragraphs(21, 1) As String

  populate_paragraph paragraphs()
End Sub

Sub populate_paragraph(ByRef replacers() As String)

  ReDim replacers(21, 1) As String
 'etc.

End Sub
```

Comment: @TinMan Yes, I tested it. With the parentheses I got an error message telling me it is necessary to pass the parameter ByRef, even though ByRef was explicitly in the procedure's method signature. The parentheses were trying to force passing the array ByVal. No parentheses, no error message.

Comment: Sorry, I was in a hurry and I misread your post.  I thought your were talking about this `populate_paragraph paragraphs) ()`.  You post is pretty clear that you mean this `populate_paragraph (paragraphs)`.  What really confused me is that I declare my array variables with the parenthesis  which changes the error to a `Type Mismatch: array or user defined type expected`  Well explained.    +1

Comment: @TinMan No problem :-) Happens to me regularly! Thanks for explaining what confused you - I've edited and hope it's clearer with the change! There are various ways to pass an array - for example as Variant.

Comment: Knowing that about the parentheses is already helping me to prevent other problems. Sorry for not marking the question as solved before, just now I have some spare time, and I did not expect answers so fast. Thank you very much for your help